# UIWebView Bug: -[UIWebView cut:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiwebview

In the `UIWebView`, if an input element containing text has focus, and a button is pressed that causes the input to lose focus, then subsequently double-tapping on the input to regain focus and selecting Cut (or Copy or Paste) from the popup bar that appears causes the `UIWebView` to crash with the error:

```
-[UIWebView cut:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10900ca60
```

Demo project: https://github.com/guarani/WebViewDoubleTapTestTests.git

I think this must be a `UIWebView` bug, any ideas?

For completeness, here are the contents of my web view,

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="button">
    </body>
</html>
```

Filed a Bug Report at Apple: 15894403

**Update 2019/05/30: Bug still present in iOS 12.0 (16E226)**

Comment: I've had a play with your code and there is nothing wrong with the way the `cut:` method works as long as you don't press your button `<input type="button">`. If you press the done button on the keyboard or just double tap without dismissing the keyboard it works fine. It's quite confusing.

Comment: There are many cases where someone inputs text into an input, presses a button, then double-taps the same input, selects the text and cuts it. So I think this is a critical bug. This bug was found by someone testing my app, who happened to perform these steps, and crashed my app.

Comment: No this isn't a bug for Apple this differently your bug. You need to handle the event for the `UIMenuItem` that you press, simples.

Comment: This is an Apple bug. The problem is the `cut:` is sent incorrectly in the responder chain, and ends up sent to `UIWebView` instead of `UIWebDocumentView`.

Comment: @paulvs i am still facing this issue in iOS 12. Did you get solution for this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an Apple bug. The problem is the `cut:` action is sent incorrectly in the responder chain, and ends up being sent to the `UIWebView` instance instead of the internal `UIWebDocumentView`, which implements the method.

Until Apple fixes the bug, let's have some fun with the Objective C runtime.

Here, I subclass `UIWebView` with the purpose of supporting all `UIResponderStandardEditActions` methods, by forwarding them to the correct internal instance.

```
@import ObjectiveC;    

@interface CutCopyPasteFixedWebView : UIWebView @end

@implementation CutCopyPasteFixedWebView

- (UIView*)_internalView
{
    UIView* internalView = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "__internal_view_key");

    if(internalView == nil && self.subviews.count > 0)
    {
        for (UIView* view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
            if([view.class.description hasPrefix:@"UIWeb"])
            {
                internalView = view;

                objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "__internal_view_key", view, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return internalView;
}

void webView_implement_UIResponderStandardEditActions(id self, SEL selector, id param)
{
    void (*method)(id, SEL, id) = (void(*)(id, SEL, id))[[self _internalView] methodForSelector:selector];

    //Call internal implementation.
    method([self _internalView], selector, param);
}

- (void)_prepareForNoCrashes
{
    NSArray* selectors = @[@"cut:", @"copy:", @"paste:", @"select:", @"selectAll:", @"delete:", @"makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:", @"makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:", @"toggleBoldface:", @"toggleItalics:", @"toggleUnderline:", @"increaseSize:", @"decreaseSize:"];

    for (NSString* selName in selectors)
    {
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selName);

        //This is safe, the method will fail if there is already an implementation.
        class_addMethod(self.class, selector, (IMP)webView_implement_UIResponderStandardEditActions, "");
    }
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self _prepareForNoCrashes];

    [super awakeFromNib];
}

@end
```

Use this subclass in your storyboard.

Have fun.

Comment: Awesome! For anyone interested just add `#import <objc/runtime.h>` to the top of the file. I wonder how many apps could be crashed with this bug. Do you think it would be ok/safe to put this in production code? Would it pass the App Store?

Comment: @PaulVon It should be safe. Nothing in there is specifically private API. Of course, it is better Apple just fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Leo. The problem seems to be related to that after pressing a button in a UIWebView, subsequent double-taps on any input do not bring up the keyboard (like they do before pressing a button), and the  Cut/Paste menu bar is displayed without the keyboard, and this is when a crash occurs if any of the Cut/Paste buttons are pressed. _Note: jQuery Mobile using Cordova does not have this problem._

Comment: @PaulVon Yes, the problem is, if you double tap on the text field, the internal `UIWebDocumentView` does not become first responder, so the responder messages are sent to the incorrect instance. `UIWebView` announces it can perform actions (by `canPerformAction:withSender:`), but has not implemented them for real.

Comment: @PaulVon I am not sure how Cordova/PhoneGap implement their wrapper, but if you can provide a sample project which I can attach to in Xcode, I can take a look.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to get you one after work today in a few hours.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46030/discussion-between-paul-von-and-leo-natan)

Comment: @PaulVon I debugged the jQuery Mobile project, and it seems somehow Javascript catches the tap events and makes the `UIWebDocumentView` first responder, so by the time the callout bar is presented and the user can select "Cut", the responder chain is correct. Whereas, removing the script elements loading the jQM library, the bug reproduces.

Comment: @LeoNatan  I have similar issue mentioned, so I have tried all given solutions here, however these solutions are failing and could not resolve issue. Apart from this any other solution? Appreciate your support.

Comment: This is a very old answer to an old problem. First, you should be using `WKWebView`. Second, what does "failing" mean?

Comment: Makes me wonder if this is reproducible in `WKWebView` or not.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind that there is no callout for cut/paste/etc. in the case, when the UIWebview is wrongly becoming first responder, then you can also fix it with this category. This does not prohibit cut/paste/etc. when the UIWebDocumentView (correctly) becomes first responder.

```
@implementation UIWebView (NoWrongPerformWebview)

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

// Swift 4 compliant version

```
import UIKit

extension UIWebView {

    override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        // Should be respond to a certain Selector ??
        return responds(to: action)
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me and cut/copy/paste worked every time I tried too! 

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested, here's the swift version of Leo Natans method :

```
import Foundation
import ObjectiveC

var AssociatedObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0


class CustomWebView: UIWebView {
    func _internalView() -> UIView? {
        var internalView:UIView? = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "__internal_view_key") as? UIView
        if internalView == nil && self.subviews.count > 0 {
            for view: UIView in self.scrollView.subviews {
                if view.self.description.hasPrefix("UIWeb") {
                    internalView = view
                    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "__internal_view_key", view, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)
                }
            }
        }
        return internalView
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self._prepareForNoCrashes()
    }

    func _prepareForNoCrashes() {
        let selectors = ["cut:", "copy:", "paste:", "select:", "selectAll:", "delete:", "makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:", "makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:", "toggleBoldface:", "toggleItalics:", "toggleUnderline:", "increaseSize:", "decreaseSize:"]
        for selName: String in selectors {
            let selector = NSSelectorFromString(selName)
            //This is safe, the method will fail if there is already an implementation.
            let swizzledMethod:IMP = class_getInstanceMethod(CustomWebView.self, #selector(CustomWebView.webView_implement_UIResponderStandardEditActions))
            class_addMethod(CustomWebView.self, selector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))
        }
    }

    func webView_implement_UIResponderStandardEditActions(this:AnyObject, selector:Selector, param:AnyObject)
    {
        let method = {(val1: UIView?, val2: Selector, val3: AnyObject) -> Void in
            self._internalView()?.methodForSelector(selector)
        }

        method(self._internalView(), selector, param);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)_internalView {
    UIView *internalView = nil;

    if (internalView == nil && self.subviews.count > 0) {
        for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
            if([view.class.description hasPrefix:@"UIWeb"]) {
                internalView = view;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return internalView;
}

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    struct objc_method_description methodDescription = protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(UIResponderStandardEditActions), aSelector, NO, YES);

    if (methodDescription.name == aSelector) {
        UIView *view = [self _internalView];
        if ([view respondsToSelector:aSelector]) {
            return view;
        }
    }
    return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks