# iOS 8 file upload crashing UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

I have an iOS application which utilizes some cordova plugins and uses the standard UIWebView wrapper.

With iOS 8, I go to upload an image in a UIWebView, the app crashes. Xcode give an "App terminated due to memory error" and not much else. This issue was also occurring in Safari initially, but Apple patched that up in iOS 8.0.1.

A couple weeks ago, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898564/ios-8-0-uiwebview-file-input-crashes-my-app) which fixed the crash issue for me. Now, however, iOS 8.1 is out and the issue is happening again. I've tried all sorts of combinations of deployment targets and base SDK settings in my CordovaLib.xcodeproj settings and my main project's build setttings, but I'm not having much luck.

I'm testing this on an iPhone 6.

Comment: It is Apple bug. iOS 8.0 have UIWebView Cut bug. refer this url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316784/uiwebview-bug-uiwebview-cut-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance